# C# webBrowser Control how to get data under mouse pointer

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

Hi 
  If I open a site in the WebBrowser control is there anyway to code a function to get data under the mouse pointer?

So what I'm wanting to do, but don't have a clue how to! is load a website (most any website) the user places the mouse over some data on the page and presses control click and on doing so the code works out what the HTML tag below the cursor and reads the inner value of it. hope that makes sense!

in fact just like the pointer control in the MS Developer tool for IE does it even manages to place a box around what would be selected...

I'm only looking for the text no images...

thanks for any help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(webBrowser.PointToClient(MousePosition))
```

Comment: WOW thank you I thought there would be loads of code to write!