# Selenium C# Get href under the mouse coordinates

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

there is a website and profiles are listed with their profile photos.
[image: Like this]

I'm trying to get href of that profile photos (i'm not trying to get href of photo, i'm trying to profile href). So i need to get element under the mouse cursor. There is simple code for do it in basic c# browser: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207003/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-how-to-get-data-under-mouse-pointer)
but i'm using Selenium driver so i think i need to do it by executing JavaScript.
So i've found that thread for using elementfrompoint with javascript on selenium but it returns me "null"
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910534/executing-javascript-elementfrompoint-through-selenium-driver)

Here is the class of that profile photos.
[image: Class]
I'm trying to get href "/en/community/ProfileUrlHere"

Edit: i've tried to use

```
ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
                    "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", 
                    Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
```

But it returns null seems like i've problems with coordinates,  "Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y" i need to get coordinates by using "event.ClientX"

```
              String s_Script = "var X, Y; "
              
               + "  X = event.clientX; "
               + "  Y = event.clientY; "
               + " alert(X);"
                + "return new Array(X, Y);";
```

But i get "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'javascript error: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined" this error.

Answer (score -1):

i've tried to use

```
ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
                "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", 
                Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
```

But it returns null seems like i've problems with coordinates, "Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y" i need to get coordinates by using "event.ClientX"

But i get "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'javascript error: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined" this error.